# regex to change certain words in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get my head around regular expressions. I thought the following would work, but unfortunately it isn't.

What I want to do:

Given a string `str` (see below) I want to replace any word that is not `shade` or `gravel` with the word `gravel`.

```
str = "gravel shade water grass people water shade";
output = str.replace(/([^gravel|^shade])/g,' gravel ');
```

`output` should equal `gravel shade gravel gravel gravel gravel shade`. What I have is close enough but a bit off.

Comment: That regex makes my skin crawl... Do you really know what it will match?

Comment: Quick explanation then, so you know what I mean by that. 1. *everything* between the outermost `[` and `]` is considered a set, resulting in a single character. 2. .. except when the first character is `^` - then it's negated. So you are matching everything not one of `g`, `r`, `a` ... Love to see what you actually got, though, as you didn tell.

Comment: @RadLexus thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `([^gravel|^shade])` matches and captures into Group 1 any one single character that is not `g`, `r`, `a`, `v`, `e`, `l`, `|`, `^`, and replace all of them with `gravel`.

You can use

```
/\b(?!(?:shade|gravel)\b)\w+\b/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cC6sC7/1)

Pattern description:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?!(?:shade|gravel)\b)` - a negative lookahead that will exclude matching whole words `shade` and `gravel`
- `\w+` - 1+ word characters (belonging to the `[A-Za-z0-9_]` set)
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

```js
var str = 'gravel shade water grass people water shade';
var result = str.replace(/\b(?!(?:shade|gravel)\b)\w+\b/g, 'gravel');
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: brilliant! thanks! i will give you the green tick when it allows me to. by the way that is good knowledge of regular expressions!

Comment: Note that if the requirement changes and you will need to replace *any non-whitespace chunks of text* that is not `gravel` or `shade` with `gravel`, you will need a [more complex approach](https://jsfiddle.net/kaxjga3t/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex solution for your problem using `split/join` and `array.map`:

```js
var str = "gravel shade water grass people water shade";
var repl = str.split(' ').map(function (w) {
           return (w!='gravel' && w!= 'shade')?'gravel':w; }).join(' ')

document.writeln("<pre>" + repl + "</pre>")
//=> "gravel shade gravel gravel gravel gravel shade"
```